How do I interact with a standard browser based date time picker component using the Atata framework?
I need to get my atata script to set a date on my web form. The web form utlizes the tailwind css framework.

            DateTime t =  new DateTime(2024 ,02,17);

            Go.To<DatesClaimAreaEditPage>()
                // .EditHeading.Should.Contain("Edit Claim")
                .DateArea.Click()
                .EditIncidentDate.Click()
                .CurrentIncidentDate.Clear()
                .CurrentIncidentDate.Set(t)
                .Report.Screenshot()
                .EditIncidentAwareness.Click()
                .CurrentDateAware.Set(t)
                .CurrentDateAware.Click()
                .EditNatmedNotified.Click()
                .SaveReload.Should.BeVisible()
                .SaveReload.Click()
                .DateArea.Click()
                .Report.Screenshot();


This is the component I pick up when inspecting the web element oin my web broswer in dev tools:
code for the web element
I tried what you see in my method above. I defined my page object class like this:
 [FindByXPath("//*[@id='claimDates']/div[1]/div/editbutton/button")]
 public Button<_> EditIncidentDate { get; private set; }

 [FindByXPath("//*[@id='DateOfIncident']")]

 public DateInput<_> CurrentIncidentDate { get; private set; }

Should I make a custom component control for this particular date time picker?

So what is the problem with your current implementation? Does it throw an exception or what?
Right, DateInput is the right Atata control to choose when dealing with standard input[type="date"].
Note that DateInput component supports formatting. The default format is "d" (short date pattern, e.g., 6/15/2009). If your date format differs, add [Format("{custom_format}")] attribute to your date input property.
Few other recommendations:

Prepend XPaths like "//*[@id='DateOfIncident']" with . to have ".//{...}".
Instead of [FindByXPath("//*[@id='DateOfIncident']")] use [FindById("DateOfIncident")].
No need to call Clear method before Set like here: .CurrentIncidentDate.Clear().CurrentIncidentDate.Set(t). Set method clears and then types the new text. When you don't want to clear input before typing, use Type method.


Thank you. I will implement your suggestions and provide feedback.
